# Enable HTTPS on AWS Elastic Beanstalk Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Im trying to enable https on my Elastic Beanstalk application and it looks like I need to have a Load Balancer. 
In my EB settings, I do have a autos calling balancer[image]

In the docs show a different page on how to create a load balancer
[image]

This configuration setting doesn't show up anymore in the elastic beanstalk settings.

I've also looked into creating a load balancer from the EC2 instance page, and attached this load balancer to my EB, created a security group that supports http and https and haven't been able to get it to work

SO my question is, what is the correct way to enable https

Comment: Did you select application loadbalancer? Which supports adding ssl certificates

Comment: It should have a secure listener option? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html

Answer (score 0):

Attached is our beanstalk configuration console, you should be able to turn on secure listener port as well.

Check with Section "To turn on the secure listener port" in [AWS doc reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html)

[image: network tier config]